# make token of Google Calendar (Google Oauth) live longer

Tags: google-calendar-api

I user google calendar API, but I have to connect myself each time to run my request.

I want to know how long the default token lives before the request doesn't go through?

And what can I do to to keep the token alive for a long time?

Answer (score 0):

### Google APIs use the OAuth2 authentification procedure.

- This means that in the first step, you need to obtain an **access token**.
- This access token usually expires after around one hour
- In order to avoid the token from expiration, you need to incorporate into your code a function to obtain a **refresh token**
- Please see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) for more information
- The calendar API offers [quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java) in nine different programming languages which include sample code snippets to set-up the obtention of refresh tokens